# Che vuol dire "mezzanìa" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> In faccia alla scrivania, nel vuoto tra due armadi, era appeso il quadro del ritratto d'ignoto d'Antonello; sulla parete 
>   opposta, sopra la scrivania, dominava un grande quadro che era la copia, ingrandita e colorata, eseguita su commissione del barone dal 
>   pittore Bevelacqua, della pianta di Cefalù del Passafiume, che risale al tempo del seicento. La città era vista come dall'alto, dall'occhio di un uccello che vi plani, murata tutt'attorno verso il mare con quattro bastioni alle sue porte sormontati da bandiere sventolanti. 
>   Le piccole case, uguali e fitte come pecore dentro lo stazzo formato dal semicerchio delle mura verso il mare e dalla rocca dietro che chiudeva, erano tagliate a blocchi ben squadrati dalla strada Regale 
>   in trasversale e dalle strade verticali che dalle falde scendevano sul mare. Dominavano il gregge delle case come grandi pastori guardiani il Duomo e il Vescovado, l'Ostèrio Magno, la Badìa di Santa Caterina e il Convento dei Domenicani. Nel porto fatto rizzo per il 
>   vento, si dondolavano galee feluche brigantini. Sul cielo si spiegava a onde, come orifiamma o controfiocco, un cartiglione, con sopra scritto COEPHALEDUM SICILIAE URBS PLACENTISSIMA. E sopra il cartiglio 
>   lo stemma ovale, in cornice a volute, tagliato per metà, in cui di sopra si vede re Ruggero che offre al Salvatore la fabbrica del Duomo e nella **mezzanìa** di sotto tre cefali lunghi disposti a stella che 
>   addentano al contempo una pagnotta.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "mezzanìa" in questo brano? Ho cercato il termine "mezzanìa" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può essere anche chiamato "mezzeria". Tuttavia, non mi sembra che le accezioni per "mezzeria" che ho trovato abbiano molto senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 2):

Dal contesto si evince che lo stemma ovale risulta tagliato per metà, in cui nella metà di sopra si vede re Ruggero che offre al Salvatore la fabbrica del Duomo e nella **metà** (mezzeria o mezzanìa) di sotto tre cefali lunghi disposti a stella che addentano al contempo una pagnotta.

Quindi in questo caso la linea di mezzanìa (o mezzeria) divide lo stemma in due parti e mezzanìa di sotto significa metà di sotto.